# Append content upon entering a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

With my code the user clicks one of the items in a list. They are redirected to another page where they can then see the item's details. It's like a shop where you click an item to view that item's details.

My code at the moment isn't doing this, but with `console.log` and other testing methods I do not get any errors so I am wondering if it's the way I've typed the code or it's not possible like this?

```js
$.each(response, (index, game) => {
  var $newLi = $('.new');
  $newLi.on("click", (event) => {
    console.log("$newLi");
    $("#gameContent").append("<h2>" + game.Name + "</h2><p>This game has a type of " + game.Type + "</p>");
  })
  $("#allGames").append($newLi);
})

const displayNewGames = (games, hasCheckbox) => {
  let output = "";
  var x = 100;

  games.forEach(game => {
    if (game.Type === "New Release") {
      x++;
      let ratingDiv = $("<div class='rating'></div>");

      for (var i = 0; i < game.Rating; i++) {
        ratingDiv.append('<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>');
      }

      for (var i = game.Rating; i < 5; i++) {
        ratingDiv.append('<span class="fa fa-star"></span>');
      }

      //return true;

      output += `<li>
        <div class=""><input id="togg` + x + `" type="checkbox"><label for="togg` + x + `" class="${hasCheckbox ? 'visible' : 'invisible'}">Compare</label></div></li>
            <li><a class="new" href=${game.link}><img class="frontGames" src="${game.image}">
          <p><b>Name:</b>${game.Name}<br>
        <b>Release Date:</b>${game.ReleaseDate}</br>
        <b>Genres:</b>${game.Genres}</br>
        <b>Retail Price:</b>${game.RetailPrice}</br>
        <b>Rating:</b>${ratingDiv.html()}</br></p></a>
      </li>`;
    }
  })
  return output;
}
```

Do note that the data that it displays is coming from a JSON file via AJAX.

In a nutshell, the user clicks an item on index.html and they are sent to another page called game.html to view the details based on that item. Only the redirection works. I need to understand why it isn't displaying the details.

I've only posted the relevant bits, but if you need me to post other bits of the code, let me know.

Comment: Your code has a fairly obvious syntax issue. Is that just an error from copying/pasting the code in to the question?

Comment: That can’t be your actual code, not even three lines in it stops making any sense. `$.each(response, (index,game) => { var $newLi = $('.new'); src=${game.image}></a>\`);`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah thats probably due to how I copied it. when i run the code it gives no errors, but doesnt work

Comment: @CBroe that line you've commented, its commented out in the code, that was for testing

Comment: apparently the timing is off with the redirection and displaying, any idea how i can improve it?